# How Firebase rules get 'request.auth.uid' field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In the main thread of the application, it is clear that, any `Firestore` queries get `request.auth` field from current `FirebaseAuth` login. But I am unsure when it comes to worker threads.

Suppose a user using my app sends some data to be stored in `Firestore` whose rules allow write based on user id. Now I add the task to Android `WorkManager`. Even before the work gets started, if the user logs out, does the work complete successfully? If no, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this [page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) for details on WorkManager basics.

WorkerManager **does not manage details within a task**, specifically the credentials used for making the API calls to Firestore.

Whatever task is stored in WorkerManager should contain either an **authentication method** that is not session based (as this session is closed or expired) or be able to generate its own session.

To explain, a Firebase user can have multiple authentication methods linked to an [account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) , one of these methods can be device based (such as using [phone number authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) or [Google Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)).

As in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), this sign-in information can be stored by the app so it can use them to self sign-in from a background task. Essentially using the credentials of the user to initiate a new login. As the credential is stored with the signed in user of the device, that is used to generate the Firebase session.

The other option works in a similar way, but has a more fixed sign-in duration, i.e. once authenticated via SMS, this token is tied to the phone number of the device and can be used to authenticate using the same credentials through **SafetyNet** for [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification).

Comment: Currently I'm using only phone auth, which requires user to type-in the otp sent. How can I self sign-in in this case? I am unable to find any documentation or code snippet related to this. If you find any, please link it.

Comment: Does this [Send a verification code to the user's phone](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) answer your question?

Comment: No, I want to know how to login to an account from worker thread.

Comment: You may have a look at anonymous auth in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) if it helps!